# SED replace in next line in yaml

Tags: sed, yaml

I am trying to replace the tag value but having no luck with sed

Here is the file looks like and i would like to replace the tag value uniquely

```
app1:
  tag: "dev-0.114"
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always


app2:
  tag: "dev-0.59"
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

this is what i tried

```
 sed -i "" "/^\(app1.*[[:space:]]*tag: \).*/s//\1dev-0.115/" values.yaml
```

but not working

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid your question is not clear. Do you want to replace which tag value by what? What is the expected output? What do you get instead? What is your Sed version?

Comment: Note that into the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/), order is not important, also the paragraph mode (the empty lines) could not exist, and you still have a valid yaml. So any sed or awk command based on visual characteristics, e.g. "paragraph mode, position of tag", may be successful once but not always. You, or a program may edit it someday, and later the same shell command that had succeeded, could then fail. It's better to edit it *always* as yaml, there is a plethora of ways to do it, using Python (or yq), Perl, Ruby etc, (importing the necessary module of each language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the `.app1.tag` value to the string `dev-0.115`, using in-place edit with `yq` from https://github.com/kislyuk/yq (which is a `jq` wrapper):

```
$ cat file.yml
app1:
  tag: "dev-0.114"
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always


app2:
  tag: "dev-0.59"
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

```
$ yq -i -y '.app1.tag = "dev-0.115"' file.yml
```

```
$ cat file.yml
app1:
  tag: dev-0.115
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always
app2:
  tag: dev-0.59
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

Using `yq` as found on some Linux systems, converting the document into JSON, doing the modification in `jq`, and then converting it back and writing to the `newfile.yml` file:

```
$ yq -j r file.yml | jq '.app1.tag = "dev-0.115"' | yq -P r - >newfile.yml
```

```
$ cat newfile.yml
app1:
  tag: dev-0.115
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always
app2:
  tag: dev-0.59
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: great answer , because of the tool scope i have to choose other answer.

Comment: I take back previous comment, this is better strategy for yaml

Answer (score 4):

You can read the **n**ext line into pattern space using the `n` command. So given

```
$ cat file.yaml
app1:
  tag: "dev-0.114"
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always


app2:
  tag: "dev-0.59"
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

then

```
$ sed '/^app1:/{n;s/tag:.*/tag: "dev-0.115"/;}' file.yaml
app1:
  tag: "dev-0.115"
  repository: kafka
  pullPolicy: Always


app2:
  tag: "dev-0.59"
  repository: nginx
  pullPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task, I'd use the simplest tool available:

```
tr -d '"' < file.yml
```